# NSDictionary into NSString conversion issue

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, type-conversion, nsdictionary

What is the problem with this piece of code?

That works:

```
NSDictionary* fact = [facts objectAtIndex:currentFactId];
[myTextView setText:[fact objectForKey:@"fact"]];
```

That doesn't work:

```
NSDictionary* fact = [facts objectAtIndex:currentFactId];
NSString *fact_string = [fact objectForKey:@"fact"];
```

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't work?  What do you get? Try logging [[fact objectForKey:@"fact"] class] and see what it returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work but still try this

```
NSString *fact_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[fact objectForKey:@"fact"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Think that the objectForKey doesn't ensures you that will be returning an NSString. Since you are assigning its value you'll need to encapsulate it like Neo said. I wouldn't do the set and the assigning without that encapsulating or, at least,  a casting to (NSString *).

Comment: If the object is not already an `NSString` then casting it to `NSString *` will not help a bit. Casting an Objective-C object to a different Objective-C type does not change the object and does not perform any conversion.